# plink 'Invalid handle': how to redirect stdin and stdout?

Tags: shell-escape, unix

In my tex file I want to call plink (command line application for PuTTY) in order to execute a remote command and read the output. When I do this I get an error 'Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid'

MWE:

```
   \begin{document}
   Calling plink from within LaTeX...

   \immediate\write18{plink -load my_session echo remote_response}

   \end{document}
```

I think this error is output by plink, not LaTeX, and I'm not the first to encounter this problem (link1: http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/plinkexe-unable-to-read-from-standard-input-the-handle-is-invalid/comment-page-1#comment-115264, link2: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/win-plink-stdin-handle-invalid.html)

The solution is appearently to 'redirect STDIN and STDOUT', and though I'm vaguely aware what it means, I'm not sure how to do this in LaTeX. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with smt like `\immediate\write18{plink -load my_session echo remote_response > bla.out 2> bla.err < bla.in}` ?

Comment: I haven't; when I try to do this for only the outputs the same error message ('Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid') is printed to bla.err. When I include the input file, the latex compiler hangs. I Don't think this is supposed to happen?

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty file `bla.in`? Is `plink` usually requiring some user input?

Comment: Can you try adding the `-batch` option?

Comment: I got a workaround by using echo and pipe the output to cmd, but I can imagine there are prettier solutions. At least it works like this: \immediate\write18{echo plink -load my_session echo remote_response | cmd}

Comment: @ Bordaigorl: If I use plink < bla.in then plink starts as if there were no arguments, regardless of what's in the file bla.in... Batch option suppresses output but didn't run the remote command

Comment: I hope that you trust the remote response!